# why do jquery getter css() method and javascript return different values for style variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started using jquery and I figured it would be wise to do the switch due to various initialization issues I was facing with loading external styles with javascript.
Anyway I have this rule defined in an external style sheet

```
#siteLogoDiv {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:100px;
color: white;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
z-index:4;
font-family: 'Courier New',Courier,monospace;
background-color: #006600;
}
#userdiv {
   position:absolute;
   left:72%;
   top:1%;
   width:17%;
   height:24px;
   z-index:1;
   font-weight: bolder;
   font-size: 12px;
   color:gold;
 }
```

I tried to access the left property in the style sheet like this:

```
var left = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('left');

alert('with no libs, left = '+left);// returned 971.265625px

left = $('div').css('left');

alert('with jquery lib, left = '+left);//returned 310.265625px
```

I got 2 different answers..using jquery, I got 310.265625px and using no libraries,
I got 971.265625px. I added both figures and got 1281.53125 whichh might be referring to a screen setting.
So is it that the left property is measured in different ways in jquery and pure javascript(no libraries)..perhaps from opposite ends of the screen?

```
<div id="siteLogoDiv">
<img id="sitenameid"   name="sitename" src='' alt="" >
<p id= 'userdiv' 

 onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0.5'; var div =  
 this;alert(this.id);createList(div,new    
 Array
('Home','About Us','Bookworm Forum','Go to Practice Exams','Logout','Account    
 Settings','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'),
    new      
  Array('../jsp/home.jsp','#','../jsp/chatforum.jsp',
'../jsp/exampage.jsp','../LogoutServlet'     ,'javascript:sendLogoutMessage();'
    ,'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'),'15%','20px',
            'yellow','silver','blue',2);" onmouseout="this.style.opacity = '1.0'"   

 ><%= "Welcome! "+email %>  </p> 
 <img src='' alt='../images/default_user_image.jpg' name='avatar' id='avatarid' 
 onmouseout="shrinkImageBySubtractor('avatarid', 50, 50);"       
 onmouseover="zoomImageByAdder('avatarid', 50, 50);" >


</div>
```

and here is the code for the createList function:

```
function createList(element,values,links, 
width,cellHeight,fgColor,bgColor,linesColor,position){

var $a = $('div'); 


var left = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('left');

alert('with no libs, left = '+left);// returned 971.265625px

left = $a.css('left');

alert('with jquery lib, left = '+left);//returned 310.265625px



var top = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('top');
alert('with no libs, top = '+top);// returned 971.265625px 
    left = $a.css('top');
alert('with jquery lib, top = '+top);//returned 310.265625px

//Other irrelevant code

      }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are comparing the same elements? How is `element` defined in your first line?

Comment: Thanks for updating, but I was actually wondering about your JavaScript code where you have `window.getComputedStyle(element, null)`, where does `element` come from? How are you getting that? Also, if that JS code above is to work with your HTML, `$('div')` obviously won't get a `p` tag. So you really might be comparing two different elements.

Comment: The element is the userDiv which is passed into the createList function from the html code..I just updated the question, please check. And thanks, I just changed the div to a p now, and the effect still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not referring to the same elements. `element` was set to `this`, `this` being the `<p>` element that is being moused over, ie. your `#userdiv` element (weird ID for a `<p>` tag...)

However, your jQuery is using `$('div')`, looking for "all `<div>` elements", and the CSS getter returns the value for the first such element.

Try `$("#userdiv")` or even `$(element)` and you *should*  see the same number.

Comment: Thanks Niel the Dark Absol and @christian314159. I had to do a clean and build and redeploy the application to see that the problem had been solved with your suggestions. You were correct, it's working fine now. I just replaced the $('div') with a $('p') as you suggested and the did a clean and build and redeployed the entire app and now its fine. Thanks. God bless you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Are different things, jQueries css() function returns de value of the css propierty. And the .getPropertyValue('left'); of javascript returns the actual position of the element. To explain it:

```
    <style>  
    .container {margin: 0 auto;position:relative}
    .elem {position:absolute; top:0; left:200px}

    </style>
    <body>

       <div class="container"> <div class="elem"></div>

    </div>
    </body>
```

Depending of the size of the window de getPropertyValue('left') function will change its return, as .container has automatics margins.

But css("left") will allways be 200px

Comment: I think the problem might be somewhere around what you posted @Viroide..I'll update the question again now so you can see what I mean. The userDiv paragraph is enclosed within a siteLogoDiv.